# How to redirect from http://domain.com:443 to https://domain.com?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I'm trying to set up a redirect from **http**://domain.com:**443** to **https**://domain.com.

Now **http**://domain.com:443 redirects me on https://**400.shtml** with code
301, moved permanently

https://domain.com:443 to https://domain.com works fine.
This strings in .htaccess doesn't help:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Why do you have a ! on your first line? Doesn't this indicate that it only redirects for ports that are not 443?

Comment: You are right. Anyway RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ ruined any site access.

Comment: If this is being done in a VirtualHost section, do you specify <VirtualHost *:443>  ?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you cannot go from http://domain.com to https://domain.com ? Why do you need to specify the port 443 in the address bar?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to set up a redirect from http://domain.com:443 to https://domain.com.

This makes no sense **whatsoever**!

You cannot listen to http and https on the same port. 443 is the standard port for https. Webservers that listen to port 443 will expect the first message it receives to be a request to set up the https session and not a http message.

Even if you decided to go against all sane advice and set up your webserver to NOT use https on port 443, so you could respond to the http://domain.com:443 request then the redirect will work but then https://domain.com will not work as this will try to use port 443 (default port for https) which you've now stopped using https - so this still won't work.

Use port 80 for http and port 443 for https like everyone else does. You can use different non-standard ports if you want (e.g. 8443) but don't mix these two standard ports up - it doesn't make sense, it's asking for trouble and it won't work.